# How return List<> on webservice (asmx) MVC/C#

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have a systema with a webservice builded with asmx, i need return a Ilist<> collection of entities but I get a error.

```
Private MyEntity db = new MyEntity();

[Webmethod]
[ScriptMethod(RespondeFormat = ResponseFormat.Json]

public Ilist<Category> AllCategories()
{
   return db.Category.ToList();
}
```

**Error:**

Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.Ilist ...

What cant I do?

Im working with visual studio 2015 / MVC5 / C# / Framework 4.5.2

Comment: don't return the interface, return the class or an array.

Comment: e.g. `public List<Category> AllCategories()`